# How to save data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app like google's keep (notes taking app) using flutter. I can add notes but when I close the app, it resets to initial state. How can I save these notes so when I come back to app, I can read my previously added notes.

Comment: Your app needs to save the notes to a database, either on a server you provide or a service such as Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

When you're saving in a list for example, and render, you're doing that on UI state which is temporary. If you want to store data to last even after the UI got refreshed, you have to use a database that will hold the data until you delete it.

If you just want to store some tiny data, for example light/dark mode preferences or login/logout sessions, you can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). For larger data, I used [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to store data in SQL database in system as a file which will be cleared after the app is memory-cleared or deleted. If you want to store the data in cloud, you can use [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
 1) Save locally on device using database. Below are the db solutions.

1. [Moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter)
2. [Floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor)

2) Save on the server, you can use [Firebase Cloud Firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore).

Answer (score 0):

Check [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) package, a lightweight and blazing fast key-value database.